# Почему при выводе массива символов (c-style) не выводится адрес первого элемента?

Tags: c++

Почему при выводе массива символов (c-style) не выводится адрес первого элемента?

```
char string[] = "Hello";
std::cout << string << "\n";
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
std::cout << arr;
```

Результат:

```
Hello
0000007DEA2FF758
```

первый массив не преобразовывается в указатель (в этом случае)?

Answer (score 6):

Потому что используется соответствующая *перегрузка оператора*

```
ostream& operator << (ostream&, const char *)
```

которая предназначена для вывода С-строк.